# Select table rows excluding first row

Tags: css, ruby, xpath, css-selectors, html-table

How to select table rows excluding first row. Number of table rows could vary.

Here is example:

```html
<table id="grdVerzekeringen" >
    <tr>
        <th>First name</th><th>Last name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Pera</td><td>Peric</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Mika</td><td>Mikic</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Zika</td><td>Zikic</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In this example I want to select table rows that have actual data not header data. I could use css selectors or XPath.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the header row uses `th`, you are lucky. Just use the following XPath expression:

```
table[@id="grdVerzekeringen"]/tr[td]
```

If the header uses `td` as well, you can use the `position()` function:

```
table[@id="..."]/tr[position()>1]
```